# How to load Kafka consumer or producer properties from application.yaml?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Currently I have this code for creating a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`.

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps()));
    factory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate());
    return factory;
}
```

How do I create the `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` object with properties from `application.yaml`? I don't want to set them inside the `consumerProps()` method.

EDIT:
My KafkaConfig class now looks like this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {
    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<Object, KafkaExampleRecord, KafkaExampleRecord> replyingKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> producerFactory,
                                                                                                       ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> repliesContainer) {
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory, repliesContainer);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> repliesContainer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> kafkaListenerContainerFactory) {

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> rc =
                kafkaListenerContainerFactory.createContainer("mytopic");
        rc.setAutoStartup(false);
        return rc;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> pf) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    }
}
```

However now I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: a KafkaTemplate is required to support replies`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot automatically configures one; simply add it as a parameter to the factory method:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
    ConsumerFactory<Object, KafkaExampleRecord> cf) {
...
```

However, you don't need to declare the container factory bean either; Boot will auto configure it for you and automatically set the KT, if it is defined as a bean.

See Boot's `KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration`.

Comment: Mhm... when I define KT as bean I get a `KafkaTemplate is required to support replies` (see my EDIT above).

Comment: Use `<Object, Object>` in the bean definition (and its pf parameter).

Comment: See the code in `KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration`; it uses `ObjectProvider<KafkaTemplate<Object, Object>> kafkaTemplate` and `this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate.getIfUnique();` - the generic types must match in order for the `ObjectProvider` to work; the actual types don't matter at runtime due to type erasure. In practice, the types really only matter for `template.receive()` operations since, when sending, the actual type is used by the serializers in the `kafka-clients`.