# IntelliJ error: Could not autowire, no beans of type found?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, apache-kafka

I am using [Spring for Apache Kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafka-template) with auto configuration. I asked some questions about it, for example [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776966/how-to-load-kafka-consumer-or-producer-properties-from-application-yaml).

Now everything seems to work, however IntelliJ (2022.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)) complains with an error message.

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'ProducerFactory<Object, KafkaExampleRecord>' type found.

[image]

Because Boot is auto configuring the producer factory with properties from `application.yaml` I don't need the bean. How do I get IntelliJ to be happy without suppressing the error? It seems that no solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889970/intellij-incorrectly-saying-no-beans-of-type-found-for-autowired-repository) was able to help me.

Comment: "I don't need the bean" so why are you using it in your code? either remove it, or make sure it can be autowired

Comment: If you haven't configured the context properly for Intellij you will get false positives. If your application runs, ignore it.

Comment: @Stultuske: I don't need them personally but the beans are needed for the Kafka library and auto configuration :)

Comment: @M.Deinum: I already tried that, it was one of the solutions from the linked StackOverflow question. Could you tell me what you mean with "properly"?

Comment: Make sure the [Spring Application Context](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html#spring-file-set) is configured for the module. Try the latest version from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2022.2+latest+builds If problem remains, file a bug with a sample project (can be privately attached) at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: so ... you need them.

Comment: Properly means that it knows about all the configurations (including the auto ones) it probably doesn't and hence you get this warning. It is a warning not an error, so if your application runs fine just ignore it.